# How can I check if a file is older than a certain time with PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-3.0

How can I check in ***Powershell*** to see if a file in $fullPath is older than "5 days 10 hours 5 minutes" ?

(**by OLD, I mean** if it was created or modified NOT later than 5 days 10 hours 5 minutes)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Here's quite a succinct yet very readable way to do this:

```
$lastWrite = (get-item $fullPath).LastWriteTime
$timespan = new-timespan -days 5 -hours 10 -minutes 5

if (((get-date) - $lastWrite) -gt $timespan) {
    # older
} else {
    # newer
}
```

The reason this works is because subtracting two dates gives you a timespan. Timespans are comparable with standard operators.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 22):

[`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path) can do this for you:

```
Test-Path $fullPath -OlderThan (Get-Date).AddDays(-5).AddHours(-10).AddMinutes(-5)
```

Comment: The -OlderThan switch is not available in PS2.0. Not sure when it was introduced, but it's definitely available in PS4.0.

Answer (score 10):

This powershell script will show files older than 5 days, 10 hours, and 5 minutes. You can save it as a file with a `.ps1` extension and then run it:

```
# You may want to adjust these
$fullPath = "c:\path\to\your\files"
$numdays = 5
$numhours = 10
$nummins = 5

function ShowOldFiles($path, $days, $hours, $mins)
{
    $files = @(get-childitem $path -include *.* -recurse | where {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days).AddHours(-$hours).AddMinutes(-$mins)) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)})
    if ($files -ne $NULL)
    {
        for ($idx = 0; $idx -lt $files.Length; $idx++)
        {
            $file = $files[$idx]
            write-host ("Old: " + $file.Name) -Fore Red
        }
    }
}

ShowOldFiles $fullPath $numdays $numhours $nummins
```

The following is a little bit more detail about the line that filters the files. It is split into multiple lines (may not be legal powershell) so that I could include comments:

```
$files = @(
    # gets all children at the path, recursing into sub-folders
    get-childitem $path -include *.* -recurse |

    where {

    # compares the mod date on the file with the current date,
    # subtracting your criteria (5 days, 10 hours, 5 min) 
    ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days).AddHours(-$hours).AddMinutes(-$mins))

    # only files (not folders)
    -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)

    }
)
```