# prompt or PS command to delete folders older than x days

Tags: windows, powershell, command, command-prompt

i'm building a setup with inno setup and i'd like to add scheduled task to clean log folders older than X days with single command.
I'm searching for some example to make powershell or prompt command, but none works.

Can you help me to find best way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much time to research this but if you would like to search for a file within a folder location continuously covering a specific time-frame you can use the following script;

```
while($true){

    # You may want to adjust these

    $fullPath = "C:\temp\_Patches\Java\Files\x86\Source"
    $numdays = 5
    $numhours = 10
    $nummins = 5

    function ShowOldFiles($path, $days, $hours, $mins)
    {
        $files = @(get-childitem $path -include *.* -recurse | where {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days).AddHours(-$hours).AddMinutes(-$mins)) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)})
    if ($files -ne $NULL)
    {
        for ($idx = 0; $idx -lt $files.Length; $idx++)
        {
            $file = $files[$idx]
            write-host ("Old: " + $file.Name) -Foregroundcolor Red
            Start-Sleep -s 10
        }
    }
}

ShowOldFiles $fullPath $numdays $numhours $nummins
}
```

You would just need to add this script to your start-up folder and change the values (E.G file path, file age, sleep). You can also append the data to a text file.

I started with the following post:
[How can I check if a file is older than a certain time with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613656/how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-older-than-a-certain-time-with-powershell/16614441)

Thanks,

Calvin

Edit: Formatting